# Add new parameters in for using Java ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am a beginner using Java and I don't find the solution for this:

```
public class Company{
  private String name;
  private int age;

  public Company(String n, int a){
    name = n;
    age = a;            
  }

  /*get and set*/

  public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Company> comp = new ArrayList<Company>();
        comp.add(new Company("Tom", 23));
        comp.add(new Company("John", 43));
        comp.add(new Company("Charles", 25));           
    }

}
```

I would like to add parameters in a for, like `email`, `address`, etc. But `.add` is for new elements, no parameters.

Comment: Add these properties (email, address, etc...) to the Company class.

Comment: Yes, I could do this, but I would like to know if I can do it in a for.

Comment: @OscarLT are you saying using `for` loop ?

Comment: Yes, Ravi. Is exists this posibility?

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking for. Is it about adding additional fields to the Company class? If so, just google "java class fields". And please remember: this community is not programming school. You need to be at least on a level to clearly communicate your problem. And you are expected to do *serious* research prior posting questions. Just dropping your homework assignment here is *not* appreciated.

Comment: Basically, that is a good question, as well as example of the code, but as mentioned above, stackoverflow is not programming school or tutorial center,you are asking for basic things. Look bellow for answers and kindly, try to study better before you ask next time :)

Comment: Ok, thank you for help me and sorry for my low level in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend the `Company` class with the `email`, `address` fields (1), update the constructor (2), and pass the arguments you want (3).

```
public class Company {
    ...
    private final String address; // 1
    private final String email;

    public Company(String n, int a, String address, String email) { // 2
        ...
        this.address = address;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...
        comp.add(new Company("Charles", 25, "street", "charles@gmail.com")); // 3
    }

}
```

If you already have an array filled with information for a specific field, you can use a `for`:

```
final List<String> emails = Arrays.asList("first@gmail.com", "second@gmail.com");
for (final String email : emails) {
    comp.add(new Company(..., ..., ..., email));
}
```

Comment: Note- that iteration bellow is foreach, shorter typing of the for loop

Answer (score 1):

You need to read about class [members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

```
public class Company{
  private String name;
  private int age;
  private String email;
  private String address;

  public Company(String n, int a, String e, String addr){
    name = n;
    age = a;
    email = e;
    address = addr;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add variables to your class (that is the place where it will be stored per each class instance, as well as name or age are at the moment

Than you have to modify constructor (or create another one) to be able take these parameters, and also it is good idea to make getters and setters to get or set these parameters individually, so it can looks like this

```
public class Company{
  private String name;
  private int age;
  private String email;
  private String address;

  public Company(String n, int a){
    name = n;
    age = a;            
  }

 public Company(String n, int a,String email, String address){
    name = n;
    age = a;            
    this.email = email;             //class instance object email is set to email from method parameter
   this.address = address;
  }

  /*get and set*/
  public void setEmail(String email){
    this.email=email; //explicit setter
  }

  public String getEmail(){
    return this.email;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Company> comp = new ArrayList<Company>();
        comp.add(new Company("Tom", 23));  //will work, because I let your constructor
        comp.add(new Company("John", 43));
        comp.add(new Company("Charles", 25));           

        Company compToAdd= new Company("preparedFoo",22);
        compToAdd.setEmail("fooomail"); //will work because setter
        comp.add(compToAdd);           


        comp.add(new Company("FooName", 30,"fooMail","FooAddress"));   //will work because new constructor

    }

}
```